# Delete all but the top-k nodes of some query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to replicate the behaviour of the following SQL query in neo4j

```
DELETE FROM history
WHERE history.name = $modelName AND id NOT IN (
   SELECT history.id
   FROM history
   JOIN model ON model.id = history.model_id
   ORDER BY created DESC
   LIMIT 10
)
```

I tried a lot of different queries, but basically I'm always struggling to incorporate finding the TOP-k elements. That's the closest I got to a solution.

```
MATCH (h:HISTORY)-[:HISTORY]-(m:MODEL)
WHERE h.name = $modelName
WITH h
MATCH (t:HISTORY)-[:HISTORY]-(m:MODEL)
WITH t ORDER BY t.created DESC LIMIT 10
WHERE NOT h IN t 
DELETE h
```

With that query I get the error `expected List<T> but was Node` for the line `WITH t ORDER BY t.created DESC LIMIT 10`.
I tried changing it it `COLLECT(t) AS t` but then the error is `expected Any, Map, Node or Relationship but was List<Node>`.

So I'm pretty much stuck. Any idea how to write this query in Cypher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following that approach, you should reverse the order, matching to your top-k nodes, collecting them, and performing the match where the nodes matched aren't in the collection.

```
MATCH (t:HISTORY)-[:HISTORY]-(:MODEL)
WITH t ORDER BY t.created DESC LIMIT 10
WITH collect(t) as saved

MATCH (h:HISTORY)-[:HISTORY]-(:MODEL)
WHERE h.name = $modelName
AND NOT h in saved
DETACH DELETE h
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you! Just while walking away from the laptop I had the thought that reversing the order might be a solution. Also the `DETACH DELETE`is of course important here. Had to smile as your username fits the solution :)